# Newbie with php/mysql UPDATE

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have a page one my site that shows all the Staff Members for my company. I would like to Update the info that I have on there using a form. I have everything GOOD, just got to get it PERFECT. :p

I have a function that should update it but it isn't.

```
  public function writeStaff($p) {
  if ( $_POST['uid'] )
  $uid = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['uid']);
if ( $_POST['level'] )
  $level = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['level']);
if ( $_POST['name'] )
  $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
if ( $_POST['pic'] )
  $pic = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pic']);
if ( $_POST['job'] )
  $job = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['job']);
if ( $_POST['about'] )
  $about = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['about']);
if ( $_POST['contact'] )
  $contact = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['contact']);
if ( $_POST['links'] )
  $links = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['links']);
if ( $_POST['username'] )
  $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
if ( $_POST['password'] )
  $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
if ( $uid ) {
$sql = "UPDATE staff SET level = $level, name = $name, pic = $pic, job = $job, about = $about, conact = $contact, links = $links, username = $username, password = $password WHERE uid = $uid";
 return mysql_query($sql);
} else {
  return false;
}
}
```

---

Next, I have the form,

```
    public function display_admin_staff() {
$uid = $_SESSION['uid'];
$name = $_SESSION['name'];
$Job = $_SESSION['jobs'];
$about = $_SESSION['about'];
$pic = $_SESSION['pic'];
$contact = $_SESSION['contact'];
$level = $_SESSION['level'];
$links = $_SESSION['links'];
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$password = $_SESSION['password'];
    return <<<ADMIN_FORM_STAFF

    <form action="/staff/$uid" method="post">
<input name="uid" type="hidden" value="$uid" />
    <fieldset>
<legend><span>Add Staff</span></legend>
<ul>
<li class="input"><label for="name">Name:</label><input name="name" id="name" type="text" size="50" value="$name"/></li>
<li class="input"><label for="level">Level:</label><input name="level" id="level" type="text" size="50" value="$level"/></li>
<li class="input"><label for="pic">Pic:</label><input name="pic" id="pic" type="text" size="50" value="$pic"/></li>
<li class="input"><label for="job">Job:</label><input name="job" id="job" type="text" size="50" value="$job"/></li>
<li class="input"><label for="about">About:</label><textarea class="resizable" name="about" id="about" style="width:267px; height:300px; resize: none;">$about</textarea></li>
<li class="input"><label for="contact">Email:</label><input name="contact" id="contact" type="text" size="50" value="$contact"/></li>
<li class="input"><label for="links">Links:</label><input name="links" id="links" type="text" size="50" value="$links"/></li>
<li class="input"><label for="username">Username:</label><input name="username" id="username" type="text" size="50" value="$username"/></li>
<li class="input"><label for="password">Password:</label><input name="password" id="password" type="password" size="50" value="$password"/></li>
</ul>
</fieldset>
<ul class="actions">
<li><button type="submit" id="complete" name="submit" class="button" value="Create This Entry!"><span>Create Staff Member!</span></button></li>
</ul>

     ADMIN_FORM_STAFF;
    }
```

---

Then, I have It all come together...

```
  $obj = new simpleCMS();

  /* CHANGE THESE SETTINGS FOR YOUR OWN DATABASE */
  $obj->host = 'localhost';
  $obj->username = 'root';
  $obj->password = 'root';
  $obj->table = 'rrdcms';
  $obj->connect();

  if ( $_POST )
    $obj->writeStaff($_POST);

  echo $obj->display_admin_staff();
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem here? *I have a function that should update it but it isn't.* is a little vague.

Comment: When I submit the form, Nothing happens. The old data thats stored in the database is still there.

Answer (score 2):

You still have to enclose all your variables with quotes within the query string, otherwise you're just pasting in bare strings, causing syntax errors.

```
INSERT INTO ... (...) VALUES ('$var1', '$var2', '$var3') etc...
UPDATE ... SET field='$var1', field2='$var2', etc...
```

mysql_real_escape_string does NOT add those quotes for you. It simply make sure that whatever it's escaping is "safe" to use in a query string.

If mysql_query() returns false, that means there was a problem, and you can get the exact description/error message with `mysql_error()`.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing $_POST as an argument to writeStaff(), but then in the function write staff you are still referring to $_POST, when it looks like you should be referring to $p, so:

```
public function writeStaff($p)
{
    if ($p['uid']) { // good
    if ($_POST['uid']) { // bad
```

However I suspect this will work as $_POST is a superglobal and available anywhere just the same as $_SESSION, $_REQUEST, etc.

You may want to try this:

```
public function writeStaff($p)
{
    var_dump($_POST);
    exit;
```

And see if $_POST even holds any values, if it does not then that's your problem. If $_POST does contain values, then refer to Marc B.'s answer, in that you are not correctly quoting out the variables.

Comment: So I did the about, but still nothing is working. Using '$p['']' does make a lot of since, but it's just not working.

Comment: "So I did the about", not sure what you mean. You did the var_dump? Where there values present?

Comment: Sorry, I meant above, i was typing to fast and didn't re-read. And yes, I tried var_dump and yes there were values present. I also made a new blank php page and tried to update the database using another code but still nothing. The way my site is set up is having everything on one php page. ((index.php)) I'm not 100% sure if thats a problem, though i shouldn't be. Do you have a mysql update script that is easy to fallow? Because everything I have tried, I've gotten no success.

Comment: @Dalton Sutton: Not sure why you are limited to using only 1 page but we can work around that. It appears that your staff update form is posting to: <form action="/staff/$uid" method="post">, what is /staff/$uid? Not sure how are making a php script from a variable like that, unless you have some apache re-write rules in place.

Comment: I do. What URL should I put it to to update it? I have it pointing to the new php page.

Comment: Well, you indicated that you only have the 1 page, so the form action should look something like: <form action=<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?> This will make it so the form posts to index.php (or whatever the name of the script is.

Comment: Tried that, all that it is updating now is the first 'block' in the row that is selected. The first 'block' is called "uid". It is updating it and making it 0.

Comment: Can you do me a favor? Can you paste the code in http://pastebin.com/ and link it? You can make it private, just paste the link here.

Comment: Which CMS are you using? The suggestions I am making may break the CMS flow, but should work: http://pastebin.com/8yNQpRUh If it doesn't work for you, you may need to solicite help from the CMS forums.

Comment: I used this: http://css-tricks.com/1907-php-for-beginners-building-your-first-simple-cms/ But I designed it so the security is a lot better.

Comment: And just tried the code you gave me, and it sill isn't working right.

Comment: Ok, here is what I would recommend; start over. The various issues that myself and others have pointed out are corrected with the code available on that website. It appears you may have skipped some steps or something was lost in translation. Start over with a clean slate and see if it fixes your problem.

Comment: Okay, Thank you so much for all your help with this project!

Comment: Np. Just make sure you pay attention to the seemingly small details; quoting variables in sql strings, using $p vs $_POST, etc. With any luck you will be up and running soon.

Answer (score 0):

Try to find errors in your query with the following code

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
```